# How did they establish in the USA, post-WW II, that a Rav had smicha prior to the Holocaust?

Tags: history, rabbis, edim-witnesses, semicha, holocaust-shoah

This is probably something that happened many times after World War II, when documentation was lost.

Here's the scenario:

A [rabbi](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/593), who had led a kehila (congregation) in a small town in Slovakia, emigrates post-World-War-II to the USA, but when he arrives in New York, he has no proof of his smicha (rabbinical ordination).

A few people in New York knew him before, in Europe, and are willing to testify that they know him to have had smicha, and that he was the [rav](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/593) of their kehilla.

Questions:

- To what board/court/Bet Din would they have gone?
- Is there anywhere *now* to go back and find out who the witnesses were?
- Did the court/Bet Din issue him another sort of document in lieu of the original?

Answer (score 7):

The main point of Smicha is to prove that you know Halacha. Many famous poskim (who didn't work as official city Rabbonim) didn't have Smicha until needed (by government etc.) Therefore, if one is knowledgeable enough to pasken, he should be able to pass a rudimentary Smicha test. If he doesn't, he can't pasken even if he has Smicha.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7494/759

Comment: and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14559/semicha-and-gneivas-daas

Comment: and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/posek-vs-rabbi

Comment: and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10147/what-is-the-meaning-of-psak

Comment: Thanks Shmuel, I did read the various links.  I believe the rabbi in question served under the auspices of Young Israel. Wouldn't all rabbis of the Young Israel ilk be capable to pasken and their psakim considered acceptable?

Comment: Shmuel, Thanks for responding and adding to your answers.  Very enlightening!